# Этимология слова колебательный

Tags: этимология

"Из школьного курса физики известно, что кол++++ельный контур является ++++++ностью конденсатора (муж.рода) и катушки (жен.рода)."

Этимология:
 Кол (эвфемизм), не любой (оценка или для вампиров), а ++++ельный.
Училка задала как из этого высказывания доказать мы произошли от роботов высаженных на Землю по теории Лема?

Comment: а зачем заменять на плюсики буквы во вполне цензурном слове?
Вы сомневаетесь в их написании?

Comment: это родительский фильтр срабатывает. неважно. помогите с этимологией!!

Answer (score 2):

Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. колѣбати (σαλεύειν), русск. коле́блю, колыба́ть «качать, укачивать», укр. колiба́ти, болг. колеба́я се «колеблюсь», сербохорв. кољѐбати, чешск. kolébati «качать, укачивать», польск., в.-луж kolebać, н.-луж. kolebaś. Сомнительно сравнение с др.-англ. sсеlfаn «качаться», др.-исл. skjalfa – то же, др.-в.-нем. sciluf «тростник». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Ни к колу, ни к неприличному глаголу  (тоже, кстати, праславянской этимологии) никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Где смотреть список литературы? Зачем смотреть?

Comment: >Где смотреть список литературы? Зачем смотреть?
  
Это все цитата. "От и до" Отсюда: 
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C
Поленился резать.
Там и список.

Comment: Спасибо большое Бегемотус!!! А что насчет происхождения человека от роботов?! Они же содержат катушки и конденсаторы.

Comment: А про конденсаторы вообще не понял. Это к чему здесь?